# Erro de SQL: ORA-29855: ocorreu um erro na execução da rotina ODCIINDEXCREATE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Estou tentando criar um índice no Oracle onde será automatizado e executado a cada hora.
Query:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TXT_NOME ON TBL_PESSOA ("TXT_PESSOA") 
INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT"
PARAMETERS ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE SYNC (EVERY SYSDATE+60/1440)')
```

Ao executar é apresentado o erro:

> ```
> Erro de SQL: ORA-29855: ocorreu um erro na execução da rotina ODCIINDEXCREATE
> ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
> DRG-50857: oracle error in drvddl.IndexCreate
> ORA-27486: privilégios insuficientes
> ORA-06512: em "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
> ORA-06512: em "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
> 29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
> *Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
> *Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
> ```

Comment: O user que tentou fazer a operação não deve ter o privilégio de criar índices. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm

Answer (score -1):

Consegui achar a solução:

Comando: `GRANT CREATE JOB TO ctx_ix_test`

Link: http://przemyslawkruglej.com/archive/2013/12/text-index-with-a-sync-parameter/